# Socket.io, client receiving message multiple times

Tags: ajax, socket.io

my website's client works normally when I open it and click on my page's button. It loads dynamically inside a div. In this page I include the javascript file that handles the server messages related to it. So the first time I click the button, the page loads, and server sends data for appending in a div. Everything good so far, but when I click again in the button for loading the page, as soon as the server sends the message it will append twice on the given div, and if I click a third time, the client will append 3 times the same data to the div and so on. It's like the connection is opened multiple times, but I don't know how to handle this.
I load the page with a simple ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "items.php",
        success: function(msg){
            $("#container").html(msg);
        }
});
```

And the include on the items.php:

```
<script src="js/items.js"></script>
```

Already tried including the items.js in an outer div, but this way It won't work.

Comment: Could you show the code where your socket is listening for connections etc?

Comment: just the default simple code I guess xD: `io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {});`

Comment: It's impossible to see what the problem is without more context I'm afraid.

Comment: it's just a simple communication between server and client. The client sends a message to server and then server should show that data for everyone to see it. Like a chat, but the client script is loaded in the page that is called into the div, seems like a connection is open when You click on the page's button but doesn't close when You click again to load the same page. Does't matter if I click on another page then come back to the same one. Multiple connection maybe